# How to specify a generic function argument and get the function's return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given is a function inside of an object like this:

```
const someObject = {
  someFunction: <T extends { name: string }>(value: T) => value.name as T["name"],
};
```

I want to receive the return type of this function when called with a more specific `T`.

```
type Fn = (typeof someObject)["someFunction"];

type Input = { name: "john" };

// SpecificFn is any because "Type 'Fn' is not generic"
type SpecificFn = Fn<Input>;
// expected SpecificFn to be `<T extends {name:"john"}>(x:T)=>T['name']` => `(x: {name:"john"})=>"john"`

type Output = ReturnType<SpecificFn>; // expected "john"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmB5ARgKycWBeGA3gFAxyJIBiArmDgJbgBcMAPACoxIAeUSYAJhEIwwAQ2TNoAJzpgA5jAC+APgAUAN1EAbKkmZsAlDFzKYmnUgB0Y5DFFC2AbQBENpM4C6AGiKKA3EREUACeAA5IMBRgxjCqIeEgAGZkyOhYOAYu8MjUtFAMYJ4BQWERAJJgoVRQAGraujEEIuJ6MM4YIAAWhUrFAPR9MADK4cB0iXTAUTB0QqJgwTBo2KJUEBHObKUwAORROzNCYCCwcnxIMsDOJeHDo+OT0-hRLBVVtfVIygEDnFyjvH4d2wDym0SgICWEQABuw-rwBEICG5GO0uoUVKouIxDCYnDs3DsPNDjKZoVjmMiWqiOt1nIoDCY0XToYF4hEUNV3jEAEpIKBUKRgLbhFgjEETMHfQKBX4ABRAEAgdDQWgiaGqMCoci0i3gOny4ECoEgsE6SC04SkMTAVC0WjsQhoAGtjgB3aL2SJgYrs4FjSVRACMMTipSSMHNlour0q1TqFmUBl9205UHeIfwfIFQpFSDF90DYCD0qAA)

Is there a way to achieve that in TypeScript?

One possible Solution is to use a constant as a helper:

```
const helper = null as unknown as Fn;

type SpecificFn1 = (typeof helper<InputValue>);

type Output1 = ReturnType<SpecificFn1>;
```

but there should be a way with only types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it should be possible to do this purely at the type level, but it is not.  Currently the only way to specify a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function type without calling the function is to use an [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) like `helper<InputValue>`, but this requires an actual function *value* (or at least a pretend function value like `const helper = null! as Fn`).

See [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#47607](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607#issuecomment-1058192563), the pull request implementing instantiation expressions:

> [I]nstantiation expressions currently have no equivalent in type land. We can't just co-opt the `T<X>` type instantiation syntax since it already means something else (i.e. apply type arguments to the generic type `T`). At least, if we did, it wouldn't be immediately obvious whether `T<X>` means "apply type arguments to generic type `T`" or "apply type arguments to generic signatures in type `T` (without instantiating `T` itself)

Presumably there could be some alternative syntax to clear up the ambiguity, but for now it's not part of the language.